# Trying to hide logo when screen shrinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I have a logo in my navbar I am trying to hide it when the screen is lower than 1024 I have tried 3 methods but none of them work, I have used the following js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() < 1024) {
      $('.miniLogo').hide();
    } else {
      $('.miniLogo').show();
    }
  });
});
```

I have also tried to set up css

```
@media screen max-width: 1024px {
.miniLogo {
    display: none!important;
  }
}
```

any ideas ? ideally cross browser compatible

Comment: How about you go look up the _correct_ syntax for such a media query …?

Comment: Edited for better code formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
            .miniLogo {
                          display: none!important;
                           }
               }
```

Should do the work

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the CSS to this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .miniLogo {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just need to change your media query a little bit. Instead of:

```
@media screen max-width: 1024px {
```

Use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
```

And you should be all set!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for hiding the logo. Try out...

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
   /* Hide logo */
   .miniLogo {
       display: none !important;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the end

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(this).width() < 1600) {
    $('.miniLogo').hide();
   } else {
    $('.miniLogo').show();
   }
});
```